# DateTimePicker Change Value on Click In windows Form Application C#

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I Am using a DateTime Picker in WindowsForm Application of C#. I initalize My dateTImePicker with `DateTime.Min` Value. What I want is that when a user clicks that dropdown It Should Change its value to `DateTime.Now` Value and show the current value in calendar but I have to first open it then close it and then reopen it to get the required date in calendar. How can I Do it in a single Click? Any Help will be appreciated.

So far I have tried these events:

```
private void GroupEndingDate_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            GroupEndingDate.Value = DateTime.Now;
        }

        private void GroupStartingDate_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            GroupStartingDate.Value = DateTime.Now;
        }

        private void GroupStartingDate_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GroupStartingDate.Value = DateTime.Now;
        }
```

Comment: It would be better to initialize your DateTime Picker to `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your dropdown event. This worked for me.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);
}

private void dateTimePicker1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: I still have to click it twice if its 1st of any month

Comment: Sorry.. I can't replicate your problem. I tried dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15); //given today's date. It works fine. Try it out in a clean temp project. I suspect you have wild code elsewhere doing something funky.

Comment: I have OP's problem as well.  Setting the `dateTimePicker`'s `Value` in the `DropDown` event does not show the correct date.  Don't initialize it in the `Form1_Load`, but in `DropDown` set it to `DateTime.Now.AddDays(3)` and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The following works just fine for me without having to click the control a second time.

```
private void dateTimePicker1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
}
```

But I agree this approach seems a little odd to me. The date will be set every time the control opens up. Why not just initialize it to `DateTime.Now` in your form's Load event?